# Catching mouse click events in VS.NET Addin possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, vs-extensibility

I'd like to be able to assign some of the custom text-manipulating functions in my Visual Studio 2022 add-in code so that they can be called by mouse events such as SHIFT-CTRL-LeftClick instead of a menu bar item or toolbar button.

Is is possible to catch the mouse keyboard events for this within vs.net extensions or must I stick with menu and toolbar buttons that are assigned to IDE keyboard hotkeys only?